# has_many / belongs_to unique associations in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I save data about parliamentary affairs in my database as `Affair`, which can belong to a `Councillor` or a `Group`. I'm new to Ruby and ActiveRecord. In former RoR versions I would have used `has_and_belongs_to_many`, and it worked also.

```ruby
class Councillor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :affair_holdings, :foreign_key => :councillor_id
  has_many :affairs, through: :affair_holdings
end

class Affair < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :affair_holdings, :foreign_key => :affair_id
  has_many :councillors, through: :affair_holdings
end

class Affair_Holdings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :affair
  belongs_to :councillor
end
```

Later in code, I want to set up a new association:

```ruby
affair.councillors << Councillor.find_by(:id => 3)
```

But for any reason it doesn't work. It gives me an error message:

```ruby
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:125:in `compute_type': uninitialized constant Affair::AffairHolding (NameError)
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:178:in `klass'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:123:in `klass'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:37:in `reader'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:70:in `affair_holdings'
from crawl.rb:196:in `affair'
from crawl.rb:233:in `<main>'
```

What is my fault? How can I solve this problem?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

The class name should be `AffairHolding` and not `Affair_Holdings`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes class name should be AffairHolding and always use singular and initial capital letters for class name